# How to get pk of an instance of a django model before saving the instance

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to upload an image using `models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)`

```
def upload_location(instance,filename):
    print("%s/%s"%(instance.id,filename))
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id,filename)
```

but its giving `"GET /media/None/image_qacfEsv.jpg HTTP/1.1"`
I have tried using slug field it worked fine but neither `id` nor `pk` is working 
I want to  use the obj ID to name the folder for image but its giving `none` in id attribute
here are my files

```
    def upload_location(instance,filename):
    print("%s/%s"%(instance.id,filename))
    return "%s/%s"%(instance.id,filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                          null=True,blank=True,
                          width_field="width_field",
                          height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: There is no `pk` before saving the object.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: Use something other than `pk`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get the `pk` before saving the object -- in fact checking if an object has a `pk` is a great way to check if it's been saved yet.

So instead, I would recommend adding a UUID field on your model.  Something like:

```
import uuid

class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ...
```

The uuid field will be unique and will be available when you create the object, so you can use that in your upload path.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem and this is how I am doing it.

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    #return "%s/%s.%s" %(instance.id, instance.id, extension)
    if not instance.id:
        Model = instance.__class__
        new_id=None
        try:
            new_id = Model.objects.order_by("id").last().id
            if new_id:
                new_id += 1
            else:
                pass
        except:
            new_id=1
    else:
        new_id = instance.id
    return "%s/%s/%s" %(Model.__name__, new_id, filename)
```

Comment: Nice approach btw but I think Mark has came up with a best solution

Comment: This is clever, but it looks like it is vulnerable to a race condition -- what if you have two uploads at the same time?

Comment: I agree though that is very rare case. Also, i am using this chunk of code for a personal website, so not a big deal. :) 
Thanks for pointing, I will avoid using this for further reference.